# Get console messages into a message box

Tags: puredata

Is there any way to get the Pure Data Pd windows console messages into a message box within the patch? I'm trying to get error messages back into the patch so that the patch can react to them.

Answer (score 4):

the only way to do this (in Pd-vanilla even) is to:

1. send all post/error messages to the stderr (with the `-stderr` startup flag)
2. redirect the stderr to stdout
3. capture the stdout with a script, reformat it and send it back to Pd via the network (preferrably UDP)
4. add a `[netreceive]` to get the messages.

something like the following:

```
$ pd -stderr 2>&1 | while true; do pdsend 9999 localhost udp; done
```

and in Pd add the following to your patch:

```
[netreceive 9999 1]
|
[route error:]
|
[list prepend set]
|
[list trim]
|
[  (
```

now whenever Pd prints a line starting with "error:" this line will appear in the msgbox.

caveats: this effectively suppresses all messages on the Pd-console.

Comment: I'm getting "-bash: pdsend: command not found". I'm puzzled. Can I run pd object's out from pd, or what, hmm?

Comment: `pdsend` is a small utility that comes with Pd. Where the actual binary lives, depends on your OS/installation (of which you haven't revealed anything)

Comment: Oh, yeah, I'm running it on raspbian wheezy.

Comment: there's the `puredata-utils` package that provides a `pdsend` binary.