# Send errors from Pure Data's terminal window?

Tags: puredata

I'm new to working with Pure Data. I can send messages from Python to Pure Data but I'm interested in trying to get error messages back. There are error messages in Pure Data's terminal window. Is it possible to get at these with a Pure Data object? Or is there another mechanism I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714494/get-console-messages-into-a-message-box?answertab=active#tab-top) by umläute to a related question could be helpful to you: use the `-stderr` startup flag in Pd and capture the `stderr`in your Python script.